# Apache Web Server sends wrong Last-Modified header for newly uploaded files

Tags: apache, windows-server-2012

I am running the Apache Web Server 2.4 on Windows 2012. Recently I've noticed that Apache always returns wrong Last-Modified header, always providing current date instead.
However, if I write something in a file, or just use Powershell's

```
Get-ChildItem -r *.* | ForEach-Object { $_.lastWriteTime = $b; }
```

then Last-Modified headers go back to normal. What is the reason?
I am updating website files by uploading an archive of changed files and then uncompressing it to the document root. Apache runs under its own user account, which does not have write permissions over the document root.

**UPDATE**

The issue stopped repeating once I've switched from WinRar to 7zip for packing/unpacking

Comment: I'm extremely confused as to what you're asking. What does Apache have to do with the code you've provided that performs operations on the file system? What is `back to normal` supposed to be?

Comment: @arco444, this code is just one way to make Apache work as expected. "Back to normal" means providing *real* last-modified date instead of the current date.